# Cannot upload zip file with multipart and URLSession Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

I am experiencing a really strange issue with uploading zip file to s3... Here is my sample code and all details:

```
 private func uploadZipFile(_ photos:URL,_ step:String,_ presignedUrlModel: PresignedUrlModel) {

        var uploadingBackgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 3)
        uploadingBackgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(uploadingBackgroundTask)
            uploadingBackgroundTask = .invalid
        })
        let success: () -> Void = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(uploadingBackgroundTask)
                uploadingBackgroundTask = .invalid
            }

        }
        let failure: (ErrorResponse) -> Void = { error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(uploadingBackgroundTask)
                uploadingBackgroundTask = .invalid
            }
        }

        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

        let uploadingRequest = URL(string: presignedUrlModel.url)!
        var request = APIhelper().getMultipartRequestBody(_type: "POST", _url: uploadingRequest, boundary: boundary)

        let body = self.formBackgroundPhotoData(presignedUrlModel, step, photos, boundary)

        request.httpBody = body

        self.session.configuration.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

                if(httpResponse.statusCode==200)
                {
                    success()
                }
                else if(httpResponse.statusCode>=400 && httpResponse.statusCode<500)
                {
                 //getting 403 errorr
                 let error = ErrorResponse(message:
                        self.errorFormatingClass.getLocalizedErrorMessage(identifier: self.errorFormatingClass.ERROR)
                        ,
                                                   identifier: self.errorFormatingClass.ERROR)
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        }
        )
        task.resume()
    }
```

I always getting 403 response:**`AccessDenied`Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content-Type", "application/zip"]**

​

Here is how I form data:

```
private func formBackgroundPhotoData(_ presignedUrlModel: PresignedUrlModel,_ step: String,_ zip: URL,_ boundary: String) -> Data {
        var body = Data()

        var key = "key"
        var value = presignedUrlModel.key
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.append("\(value)\r\n")

        key = "AWSAccessKeyId"
        value = presignedUrlModel.AWSAccessKeyId
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.append("\(value)\r\n")

        key = "signature"
        value = presignedUrlModel.signature
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.append("\(value)\r\n")

        key = "policy"
        value = presignedUrlModel.policy
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.append("\(value)\r\n")

        let filename = zip.lastPathComponent
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: zip) else {
            #if DEBUG
            debugPrint("backgroundupload", "dataisnull")
            #endif
            return Data()
        }

        let mimetype = mimeTypeForPath(url: zip)

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(data)
        body.append("\r\n")

        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        return body
    }
```

Here is multipart request:

```
 public func getMultipartRequestBody(_type: String, _url: URL, boundary: String) ->URLRequest
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: _url)
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.timeoutInterval = 300
        request.httpMethod = _type
        return request
    }
```

Now, I know this tons of code, and perhaps nobody will take a look... All I am asking: please provide an example for **uploading zip or images to AWS S3,** **without adding S3 framework for uploading files**..

Our whole team does not know what to do :(

Comment: Glancing at the code to build the `multipart/form-data` request, that looks OK. But your error message makes me think that the issue isn’t the structure of the request, but perhaps the policy. Is it possible that your policy is prohibiting the uploading of zip files? (It’s not uncommon to prohibit the uploading of zip/exe/com files as those are common computer virus vectors.)

Comment: it works well in Android... Amazon s3 accepts zip files, the problem is only in IOS

Comment: Hey, any tips on how you resolved this